# What is the difference between exit and stop in ssh multiplexing commands?

Tags: ssh

The man page for ssh says that there are these three commands you can run on multiplexing ssh sessions:

- "cancel” (cancel forwardings)
- “exit” (request the master to exit),
- “stop” (request the master to stop accepting further multiplexing requests).

I think I know what "exit" does, because my pid goes away when I call it,  when I call "cancel", lsof shows just my main ssh session and the rest of the port forwards disappear.  But the same thing appears to happen if I call "exit" or "stop".  So what is the difference between those?

Answer (score 2):

`exit` will terminate all running muxed connections.  `stop` will simply accept no further new muxed connections.  If you have a session open, it will be terminated with `exit`, but will be left until autonomously closed with `stop`.

Comment: So if I want to boot people riding my connection, use exit, if I want to be nice I use stop?

Comment: Well, other people can't "ride" your connection (unless they are logged in as you), but if you have an active task open in another terminal, it will be killed off with `exit`, but not with `stop`.  With the latter, when the final connection in use is dropped, the Control connection will self-terminate.